# Protractor in Windows 7 Issue

Tags: java, node.js, angular, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I took as a guide the setup steps from [Protractor](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) and still can not run a test.

Below I have the current image from the system and the exception error.

```
npm -v
3.10.10

protractor --version
Version 5.1.1
```

After I run `webdriver-manager status`

```
I/status - selenium standalone version available: 3.0.1 [last]
I/status - chromedriver version available: 2.27 [last]
I/status - geckodriver version available: v0.14.0 [last]
I/status - IEDriverServer is not present
I/status - android-sdk is not present
I/status - appium is not present
```

After I run `webdriver-manager start`

```
C:\Users\n.markakis\Downloads>webdriver-manager start
[15:49:39] I/start - java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\
Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\chro
medriver_2.27.exe -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\n
pm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\geckodriver-v
0.14.0.exe -jar C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\
node_modules\webdriver-manager\selenium\selenium-server-standalone-3.0.1.jar -po
rt 4444
[15:49:39] I/start - seleniumProcess.pid: 1404
15:49:40.173 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75'
15:49:40.174 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
2017-02-10 15:49:40.189:INFO::main: Logging initialized @208ms
15:49:40.232 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
15:49:40.232 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver registrat
ion is skipped:
Unable to create new instances on this machine.
15:49:40.233 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
15:49:40.233 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not re
gistered
15:49:40.238 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver regi
stration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities [{browserName=safari, version=, platform
=MAC}] does not match the current platform VISTA
2017-02-10 15:49:40.267:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.15.v20160210
2017-02-10 15:49:40.287:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletC
ontextHandler@51081592{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2017-02-10 15:49:40.389:INFO:osjs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@
3e6fa38a{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:4444}
2017-02-10 15:49:40.390:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @410ms
15:49:40.390 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running
```

Below I have the `conf.js` file and a simple `spec.js`.

```
 //conf.js
 exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine',
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['spec.js'],
};

// spec.js
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
    it('should add a todo', function() {
        browser.get('https://angularjs.org');

        element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write first protractor test');
        element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

        var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
        expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
        expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write first protractor test');


        todoList.get(2).element(by.css('input')).click();
        var completedAmount = element.all(by.css('.done-true'));
        expect(completedAmount.count()).toEqual(2);

    });
});
```

In the project's path I run `protractor conf.js` and this is the error:

```
C:\Users\n.markakis\Desktop\angulartest>protractor conf.js
[16:15:32] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:15:32] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
[16:15:34] E/runner - Unable to start a WebDriver session.
[16:15:35] E/launcher - Error: WebDriverError: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cf
d9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provid
e any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 201 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:48:19 -0
700'
System info: host: 'nmarkakis', ip: '10.10.33.23', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch
: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=session not created exception
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cf
d9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 445c29ade3bc107eeb5d284587184d6f
    at WebDriverError (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\prot
ractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:27:5)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:505:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:440:13)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(11000)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\
node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:816:17)

    at Timeouts._scheduleCommand (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1500:25)
    at Timeouts.setScriptTimeout (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_m
odules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1483:17)
    at browser_.ready.browser_.ready.then.then (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roam
ing\npm\node_modules\protractor\lib\runner.ts:281:49)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\n
ode_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1366:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\
protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
    at asyncRun (C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor
\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2813:27)
    at C:\Users\n.markakis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modu
les\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
[16:15:35] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
```

I have repeat the installation steps from protractor version `4.0.10` to `5.1.1`.

Chrome versions from `54` to `56`.

At last I tried the setup in a OS X El Capitan with same versions and everything worked... but the needs are in a windows' os.

If a detail missing, please notate it for immediate reply.
Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: If you don't have the grid set-up, I would suggest not to use 'seleniumAddress' in the config file. Try removing that from your config file. Also, add the jamsinenodeoptions to handle timeouts

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I removed 'seleniumAddress' and I also add 'jamsinenodeoptions'.

Comment: I do not agree with the comment above. You are using the `seleniumAddress` and that makes sense since you launched with a selenium standalone server with `webdriver-manager start`. I would suggest taking that url (`http://localhost:4444/wd/hub`) and navigating to it on Chrome. From there you should be able to manually start a Chrome session. If you cannot navigate to that url, I would check your environment if localhost is 127.0.0.1. `jasmineNodeOptions` is important for your Protractor test after it launches.

Comment: I navigated it on Chrome. After trying to create a new session, I have the followings on terminal: `Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on
port 19761
Only local connections are allowed.
10:07:33.571 INFO - Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds t
rue on the remote end
[1.166][SEVERE]: Unable to receive message from renderer
10:07:34.392 INFO - Detected dialect: OSS
10:07:34.392 INFO - Done: [new session: Capabilities [{browserName=chrome}]]
` Thank you for your help @cnishina

Comment: Hmmmm... review your `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file to see if you have localhost redirecting to 127.0.0.1. Have you tried clearing out the folder and downloading chromedriver again? Have you tried older versions? Did previous versions of chromedriver work?

Comment: Host file it is configured as you proposed. I tried older versions of many dependencies, nothing worked in windows 7. I installed it in windows 10 and everything seems to work fine. It would be useful if someone works in win7 to post the versions that are in usage. Thanks @cnishina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this error, was the internal corporate antivirus. It was blocking the chromedriver.exe...